# Separating the currents

Tags: current

I got a big problem that I have to put these to motors together like this but they have same working voltage but different currents and that's what makes the second motor doesn't work correctly because the first motor has more resistance.

(I HAVE NO OTHER WAY TO PUT THEM TOGETHER refer to no access to GND!!!)

Otherwise I will lose a 4000$ board and make a new one :( !!

[image]

I looked around the KCL and separated the current routs but did't worked too cus the short circuit has less resistance than the B1:

[image]

So anyone can help me whit separating these currents?!! Or even suggesting to add a new circuit in the schematic?!!

Comment: Are you putting 440V at VCC?

Comment: Why do you have no other way to put them together? What are you trying to accomplish? Assuming your supply voltage is 220V, the correct way to connect the motors is in parallel so that each motor gets 220V.

Comment: No the VCC is 220V

Comment: You can add a new circuit, but not change the way the motors are connected? Come on, this is ridiculous.

Comment: The VCC and B2 and GND are fixed on the board but I have to add B1 right in the middle

Comment: I just have access to the VCC and the B2!!!

Comment: You need to use some jumper wires or something to put B1 in parallel with B2. Putting them in series will not work if the currents need to be different (and also if you can't double VCC). It's basically down to KCL: components in series have the same current.

Comment: the problem is I don't have access to the GND to make it parallel!!!

Comment: What do you mean you don't have access to ground? One of the motors is connected to it.

Comment: The B2 and GND are internal and I have access to an external  box only that contains the B2 wire and the VCC

Answer (score 2):

Short circuit the original B2 connections and add your B1 and B2 in parrallel on the location where you can still make changes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh3Jdo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Tnx for the answer but I can't short circuit the b2 because I don't have access to the GND!!!

Comment: Do you have any pictures or so? Because GND is the most common connection on a normal circuit board, it's hard to believe you have no acces. 

Is the motor connected with wires? You can simply cut the wires right?

Comment: I read your new comment, is B2 already installed and B2 not yet?

Comment: No it's not like that...the B2 is internal I cant even see it, It's a machine the already has been made whit this motor and now I have to add the B1 for some purposes and I the B1 can use the GND through the B2.

Comment: And are these the only connections in your box, or are the other connections from other parts of your machine?

Comment: The B2 is already installed and B1 need to be added.

Comment: They are the only!!!

Comment: Hm, then it's not possible. Unless you can get extra power into the box somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start off by saying that I really don't know how well, or even if, this will work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBCOmB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea with the transformer is that you wire it "backwards" so that the 5V side is the primary and the 220V side is the secondary.
The 900mA flowing through the primary is possibly stepped down to 20mA in the secondary (given the appropriate turns ratio and some luck).

I haven't done any calculations or simulations, so try it at your own risk ...